# What is difference between OpenGL programing with GLUT and Without GLUT

Tags: opengl, graphics

I want to start developing graphic programing using OpenGl

To kick start I am following [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started)

I came across programing with GLUT and without GLUT but as being new to OpenGL in am even more confuse how to go with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GLUT is the **OpenGL Utility Toolkit**

It does stuff like this:

- Multiple windows for OpenGL rendering
- Callback driven event processing
- Sophisticated input devices
- An 'idle' routine and timers
- A simple, cascading pop-up menu facility
- Utility routines to generate various solid and wire frame objects
- Support for bitmap and stroke fonts
- Miscellaneous window management functions

You can find more about it [here](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/).

Answer (score 1):

GLUT was designed as a lib for simple demos and tutorials. Maybe one cannot create full AAA game title using it... but for learning/teaching it is a great tool.

GLUT is very old right now, so look for FreeGlut which is an alternative that handles not only basic GLUT features but also gives some more advanced features: like fullscreen game mode, etc.

http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/